# Converting to unicode regardless of python version

Tags: python

I am calling a function which requires a unicode object.

I don't know whether the users of my script will have python 2 or 3.

How can I convert a string to a unicode object in a python-version-independent way?

I've seen some answers that are asking me to import builtins but I've read that its bad practice so I was wondering if there was another way. Also, when I even try to import builtins it does not let me so I can't go that route.

Comment: Do you get specific enough errors in either case to `try/except` the various cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check python version and then use corresponding method.

```
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    #use just str
else:
    #use unicode(str)
```